# Eden Editor Placing Neutral UGVs

Tags: arma-3

I am using the latest build of Arma3 (As of this post) with the Eden Editor.
(Without mods)

I am trying to place an empty UGV that does not belong to any side.
When I placed it, I made sure that the UGV is empty, but it still goes onto NATO fraction.
The UGV is also not controlled by anyone.

And when I ran the game, the CSAT A.Is kept attacking the UGV even though  it was empty and uncontrolled.

I looked around the props to place fractionless UGVs, but there weren't any.
The attributes does not provide changes to the fraction of the UGV.

So, how do I place a UGV in the editor that is neutral to everyone?

Answer (score 2):

It is an unmanned vehicle so it requires a fraction even when "empty". Try to just assign it as Civilian or Independent and you should be good.